# how to skip creating table code if table exist in android

Tags: android

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS not working

Comment: Use SharedPreferences to store a boolean value that you set to true after creating the table. On startup, check if that value is true, if it is, you can skip creating the table

Answer (score 1):

Note : `onCreate` called only once when database created and when you change version number then it will call `onUpgrade` function.So don't worry it will create only once,anyway you may use

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST` will create the table if it doesn't exist, or ignore the command if it does.So change

```
String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE LibLogin ( " + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + "password TEXT, "+ "status TEXT )";
```

to

```
String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LibLogin ( " + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + "password TEXT, "+ "status TEXT )";
```

Comment: @Nitin what do  you mean be not working?Try to clear your project and also delete existing app from device/emulator.

Comment: sir, can you send me your email id? I want to send you my complete code there. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

onCreate  will be called only once when you install your app first time. Onupgrade will be called if you change the version number of your DB, so it won't be executed everytime you run your applicacion (as Giru said) ;)

Take a look to your version number in your constructor and don't change it if you don't want re-create your DB.

Answer (score 0):

why you don't work with online database and use json string for download date. in this way you can create web site and people use the service on pc and not only on android :)